# pthread parallel processing

Tags: opencv, pthreads

Need urgent help on thread: the goal here is the separtemask will take each image and separate different contours and for each contour in the image it will call handleobject thread. So every for loop will call the handeobject thread. However, object index variable needs to be passed in each thread. But only last value of objectndex is passed, this is becuase the speratemask function loops and repalces the value of obj.objindx and only the last value of obj.objindx is 
passed to all the threads. Is there anyway to pass each objectindex
value in handleobject. The code runs fine if we uncomment the pthread_join(tid[objectIndex],NULL); but it will not give a parralel program

```
void separateMask(IplImage *maskImg)
{    
  for(r = contours; r != NULL; r = r->h_next)
  {
    cvSet(objectMaskImg, cvScalarAll(0), NULL);
    CvScalar externalColor = cvScalarAll(0xff);
    CvScalar holeColor = cvScalarAll(0x00);
    int maxLevel = -1; 
    int thinkness = CV_FILLED; 
    int lineType = 8; /* 8-connected */
    cvDrawContours(objectMaskImg, r, externalColor, holeColor, maxLevel, thinkness,lineType, cvPoint(0,0));;
    obj.objectMaskImg1[objectIndex]=(IplImage *) malloc(sizeof(IplImage));
    obj.objectMaskImg1[objectIndex]=objectMaskImg;
    obj.objindx=objectIndex;
    obj.intensityOut1=intensityOut;
    obj.tasOut1=tasOut;
    pthread_create(&tid[objectIndex],NULL,handleObject,(void *)&obj);
    //pthread_join(tid[objectIndex],NULL);
    printf("objectindx %d\n",obj.objindx);
    objectIndex++;

  }
  // cvReleaseImage(&objectMaskImg);
  //cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
  printf("Exitng Separatemask\n");

}


void* handleObject(void *arg)
{
  int i, j;
  handle *hndl;
  hndl=(handle *) malloc(sizeof(handle));
  hndl=(handle*)arg;
  pthread_mutex_t lock=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
  IplImage *pImg;
  float statistics_ratio[3][9];
  pthread_t tid3;
  tas3 tas2;
  pImg = cvLoadImage("image.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
  if(pImg == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to load image %s\n", "tiff file");
    return ;
  }
  tas2.pImg1=pImg;
  printf("tst%d\n",hndl->objindx);
  tas2.x=hndl->objindx;
  tas2.objectMaskImg1=hndl->objectMaskImg1[tas2.x];
  tas2.statistics_ratio[3][9]=statistics_ratio[3][9];
  double mean = average_intensity(pImg, tas2.objectMaskImg1); 
  int total = total_white(pImg, tas2.objectMaskImg1);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

  printf("Exiting handle object thread_id %d\n\n", pthread_self());
}
```

Comment: I have one extra question. My attached code only identifies contour that are not lebeled, performs only on 1 and zero labeled masks. My input mask images are actually labelled with 1,2,3,4.... of each contour. Example, first contour is labeled as 1, second is is labeled as 2, intead of only 1 for all contours. How can modify my code so I may be able to separate each contour separately base on the labeled image. Example contour1 a separate image, contour2 another separate image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function appears to have issues

```
void* handleObject(void *arg)
```

Firstly

```
    pthread_mutex_t lock=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
```

this is a locally created mutex - but created WITHIN the thread function. So you lock it but since nothing else can see the mutex, why do you need it??? It gives no synchronization functionality if no other threads can see it.
Secondly

```
    float statistics_ratio[3][9];
    pthread_t tid3;
    tas3 tas2;
    pImg = cvLoadImage("image.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    if(pImg == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to load image %s\n", "tiff file");
        return ;
    }
    tas2.pImg1=pImg;
    printf("tst%d\n",hndl->objindx);
    tas2.x=hndl->objindx;
    tas2.objectMaskImg1=hndl->objectMaskImg1[tas2.x];
    tas2.statistics_ratio[3][9]=statistics_ratio[3][9];
```

you create a local uninitialised 2d float array `statistics_ratio`, do nothing with it then assign it to another locally created object member. This appears to be meaningless, as does the declaration of another pthread instance `tid3`.

It doesn't really matter since nothing else can see the thread but you return from inside this function if `pImg == NULL` without first unlocking the mutex.

It is very hard to see why your code doesnt work or what it is meant to do, but perhaps the things highlighted above may help. You are creating a lot of local variables within your thread functions which are not being used. I am not sure if you need some of these to be global instead - particularly the mutex (if indeed you need one at all).

Comment: Thanks for all the response. I have one extra question. My attached code only identifies contour that are not lebeled, performs only on 1 and zero labeled masks. My input mask images are actually labelled with 1,2,3,4.... of each contour. Example, first contour is labeled as 1, second is is labeled as 2, intead of only 1 for all contours. How can modify my code so I may be able to separate each contour separately base on the labeled image. Example contour1 a separate image, contour2 another separate image.

Comment: the second answer is more focused than the first.  But both are respectively correct in different view.  Thanks to both.

Answer (score 1):

I think your initial problem is that you're reusing the `obj` structure that you're passing to the created threads so you'll have data races where the thread just created will read information that's been overwritten with data intended for another thread.

The loop that creates the threads has the following structure:

```
for(r = contours; r != NULL; r = r->h_next)
{
    // initialize obj with information for the thread
    // ...

    // create a thread and pass it a pointer to obj
    pthread_create(&tid[objectIndex],NULL,handleObject,(void *)&obj);

    // some other bookkeeping
}
```

Since you immediately re-initialize obj on the next loop iteration, who knows what data the thread function is going to get?  That's why things work if you join the thread after creating it - the `obj` structure remains stable because the loop blocks until the thread is finished.

Change the loop to look something like:

```
for(r = contours; r != NULL; r = r->h_next)
{
    // instead of using `obj`, allocate a struct using malloc
    handle* threaddata = malloc(sizeof(handle); // note: I'm not sure if `handle` is the right type

    // initialize *threaddata with information for the thread
    // ...

    // create a thread and pass it the threaddata pointer
    pthread_create(&tid[objectIndex],NULL,handleObject,threaddata);

    // some other bookkeeping
}
```

Then `free()` the data in the thread function after it is finished with with (ie., the thread creation code creates and initializes the block of data then passes ownership of it to the thread).

Note that this might not be as straightforward as it often is, becuase it looks like your `obj` structure already has some per-thread information in it (the `objectMaskImg1` element looks to be an array it each element being intended for a separate thread). So you might need to do some refactoring of the data structure as well.

Finally, there are several other outright bugs such as immediately overwriting pointers to blocks allocated by malloc():

```
obj.objectMaskImg1[objectIndex]=(IplImage *) malloc(sizeof(IplImage));
obj.objectMaskImg1[objectIndex]=objectMaskImg;
```

and

```
hndl=(handle *) malloc(sizeof(handle));
hndl=(handle*)arg;
```

In addition to the pointless use of the mutex in the `handleObject()` thread function as mentioned by mathematician1975 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11460092/12711).

A fair bit of the code in the thread function (copying or attempting to copy data locally, the mutex) appears to be stuff thrown in to try to fix problems without actually understanding what the problem is.  I think you really need to get an understanding of where various data lives, how to copy it (as opposed to just copying a pointer to it), and how to manage the ownership of the data.